# POSTGRES CONSTRAINT CHECK

Tags: postgresql

```
CONSTRAINT proper_matricula CHECK (matricula ~  '[a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z]' OR '[0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9]')
```

);

Trying to do a constraint check that sees if a given car plate is valid .
It Gives me this error
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "[0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9]"

Comment: I'd try `marticula ~ '...' OR marticula ~ '...'`.

Comment: @bereal didnt work unfortunately . Thanks though

Comment: That will work just fine. However, you don't show the complete statements you ran and the actual error for the fixed attempt, so all I can do is vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

First do this:

```
CONSTRAINT proper_matricula 
CHECK 
(
  matricula ~  '[a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z]' 
  OR '[0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9]'
)
); --  <<=== Extra ')'
```

If you format your code properly, you can easily see that there's an extra `)` (right bracket) in your `CONSTRAINT` declaration - just delete that and that will help.

However, see other errors below which also require correction!

- You have no `ALTER TABLE test ADD` in front of the `CONSTRAINT` declaration.
- Finally, you need to duplicate the field name - `OR matricula = '....'

```
(
   matricula ~ '...'
   OR
   matricula ~ '...'
)
```

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IBcWYeia).

Edit - in response to OP's comment.

You can also do this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_2 
(
  matricula TEXT NOT NULL

  CONSTRAINT proper_matricula 
  CHECK 
  (
    matricula ~  '[a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z]' 
    OR 
    matricula ~ '[0-9][0-9][a-Za-Z][a-Za-Z][0-9][0-9]'  
  )
);
```

The `CONSTRAINT` either has to be **in** the `TABLE` definition itself or else you have to specify the

```
 ALTER TABLE test ADD...
```

otherwise, how's the server to know to which `TABLE` you're referring - it could be any of the tables in the database/schema?

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vVe7S7bV).

Finally, as has been pointed out, you should **always** include as much relevant information as possible in your question. In this question, it would have been useful to know whether the `CHECK` was already part of a `TABLE` definition **or** a free-standing piece of code. FWIW, I've covered both cases now!

Comment: Thanks man. what the guy supplied on top was true. Why do i need that ALTER TABLE test add?

Comment: @Kripthonite - responded to your comment in the answer itself!

Comment: You did not show the table ddl. There is no way then we can tell whether it is an existing table or the constraint is part of the creating the table. Considering the way it is written @Vérace assumed an existing table (as I initially did). If that is incorrect then you do not need ALTER TABLE, but you would need the *extra* ')'. Takeaway: **always post complete ddl**.

Comment: @Belayer - I covered **both** possibilities! You are correct to point out the bit about **complete** DDL - I'll edit my answer.